# EF Core transaction with row version configuration not working

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, transactions

I am using Entity Framework Core v8.0.3, with PostgreSQL provider.

I have a model which is a mapping class holding the `quantity` of a specific `Item` a `User` has.

```
public sealed class UserItem : IEntity
{       
    public uint Version { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public required Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public Item Item { get; set; }

    public required Guid ItemId { get; set; }

    public required decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the associated Entity Configuration class, as you can see, the `Version` property is being used as the RowVersion:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<UserItem> builder)
{
    builder.Property(x => x.Version)
        .IsRowVersion();

// Rest of class.
}
```

With this configuration, I am expecting a `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` to be raised if there are any concurrent updates, here is the code in my service:

```
await using var transaction = await _context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(cancellationToken);

var command = new CommandContext
{
    User = user
};

try
{
    var item = await GetWithUserItem(user.Id, itemId, cancellationToken) ?? throw new ItemNotExistsException(itemId);
    var userItem = item.UserItems.SingleOrDefault();

    if (userItem is null || userItem.Quantity < 1)
    {
        return new CommandResult
        {
            IsSuccess = false,
            Description = $"You don't have enough of {item.Name}",
            CommandContext = command
        };
    }

    userItem.Quantity--;
    var result = item.Use(command);
    _context.Users.Update(user);
    _context.UserItems.Update(userItem);

    await transaction.CommitAsync(cancellationToken);
    return result;
}
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
{
    _logger.LogWarning(ex, $"Concurrency issue during {nameof(User)} Id '{user.Id}' using {nameof(Item)} Id '{itemId}'. Retrying action.");
    // Rest of method
}
```

However, when I purposefully do concurrent updates on this record, the exception does not get raised. I am definitely making concurrent changes, but when the line `await transaction.CommitAsync(cancellationToken);` is called I'm expecting an exception to be raised and that isn't happening.

Can anyone help shed more light on this?

Comment: Invoke SaveChangesAsync before  transaction.CommitAsync(cancellationToken)

Comment: @Damien consequently, it also means I need to use `ReloadAsync` on the object to force the EF cache to recognize the updated value(s) in the DB before a retry is made.